# Compiler Baremetal (arm-none-eabi) - Compiler Implementation

Tags: c++, c, arm, embedded, cross-compiling

It is common practice to declare stack variables (variables allocated on the excecuting stack rather than dynamically or statically) at the entrypoint of the function rather than mixed with instructions inside the function.
See Example 1.a and 1.b.
This helps with a better readability and was with older language even required.

With modern C/C++ it is no longer required (..but still good practice).

**My Question though:**
How does the compiler solve it if stack variables are inside a function rather than at the entry point.
See Examples 2.a and 2.b how i can imagine he solves it.
***What is ACTUALLY HAPPENING?***

> 1.a) Example (Common Practice / Best Practice)

```
void main()
{
    int a = 3;      // best practice
    bool c = false; // best practice

    a += 16;

    if(a == 5)
    {
        c=false;
    }
}
```

...rather than ...

> 1.b) Example (Uncommon)

```
void main()
{
    int a = 3;
    a += 16;

    bool c = false; // variable after some instructions executed..
    if(a == 5)
    {
        c=false;
    }
}
```

> 2.a) Possible compiler solution (A)

```
void main()
{
    int a = 3;
    a += 16;

    bool c = false; // COMPILER CUTS THIS LINE AND MOVES IT UP UNDER "int a = 3;"
    if(a == 5)
    {
        c=false;
    }
}
```

> 2.B) Possible compiler solution (B)

```
void main()
{
    int a = 3;
    a += 16;

    { // COMPILER ADDS SUBSECTION IN ORDER TO INTRODUCE NEW VARIABLES ON STACK
        bool c = false; 
        if(a == 5)
        {
            c=false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Common/best practice" is very subjective. And many people recommend defining variables as close to their use as possible (helps grouping code, and you don't have to jump much to find a variables definition when reading the code).

Comment: As for how it's solved, one way is to simply reserve space at function entry for *all* variables, no matter their scope or grouping within the function. If you really want to know (for you specific compiler and target system), look at the generated machine code.

Comment: It is not difficult for a compiler to keep track, some variable might be at sp-8 for a while then push an item now that variable is at sp-12 for a while pop something off the variable is now at sp-8 again.  control the execution paths through the function which compilers also already do.  in the grand scheme of things this is not in any way a difficult task for compilers they have other more complicated tasks to worry about.

Comment: Also note that while automatic (local non-static) variables are usually stored on the stack (even through it's not something specified in the C specification), a good compiler doesn't really use `push` or `pop` instructions to handle them. Instead it just reserves a chunk of the stack for its variables, and then uses offsets from the stack-pointer to access the variables.

Comment: what is your definition of common practice you looked at the output of maybe one or two popular compilers?  language like that somewhat ruins your whole question.  and this has nothing to do with C or C++, there is no need to keep the stack pointer static thorugh a compiled C function nor C++ nor any other compiled language as they all end up being machine code anyway which doesnt know if it had been compiled before being assembled or not.  B, C, D, Pascal, Rust, ADA, etc...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude understood, just trying to illustrate the point.

Comment: @old_timer Oh I didn't really mean it as a reply or comment for you, but for the OP. :)

Comment: The question is a generic coding style question, the title does not relate to the question at all, and neither do three of the five tags.  The answer is not dependent on the compiler or the platform.

Comment: You would do well also to remove the contentious and inaccurate pre-amble to your question and just ask the question.   "_With modern C/C++ it is no longer required (..but still good practice)._" - no, it was never good practice - exactly the opposite - minimal scope is always preferable.  Moreover it is not a "modern C/C++" thing either, it was never necessary in C++, and for C you could always declare variables at the start of _any_ `{...}` delimited block, not just function blocks.

Comment: This has been asked many times before. There is typically no relation between where inside a function a variable is declared and the point in the machine code where memory is allocated.

Comment: @all Thanks. Well true, good practice is totally subjective (I like stack variables up front so i can visually see how "heavy" a function is concerning stack usage. But i can understand the opposite as well, to limit the scope as much as possible, but me personally, i would even show it by inserting a non-required {}-section.

Comment: @aphardt : I'd say that _good style_ is subjective, _good practice_ can be - and mostly is - objective.  Stack usage of a function can be reported by the compiler in some cases; for example armcc will generate that information and it can be used by armlink to report in the link map file stack usage for an entire call chain, which is much more useful, as it can be used to determine stack requirement when applied to `main()` or task/thread entry points.  That is to say it is better to apply _tools_ to that task than coding _style_.

Comment: None of the variables in your examples *need to be on the stack at all*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When, how and where the compiler instantiates or allocates such variables is entirely implementation dependent.  It may create a stack frame for all variables at the start of the function, or it may extend the stack frame at the point of declaration, or it may not use the stack at all and use register storage instead.

The language only requires that the correct semantics are implemented; that the variable is not *in scope* (i.e. cannot be referenced by code) before it is declared, and that the scope ends after the closing `}` of the block in which it was declared.

Comment: Ok. My question is more targeting user-controlled optimization (!= compiler optimization), so what i can and should do to write fast and low-foodprint code.

Comment: @aphardt : If it were to have any optimisation at all, which is doubtful, it would be the kind of micro-optimisation that is best left to the compiler - as a developer you should concentrate on efficient algorithms, code structure and appropriate data structure selection - you will achieve far more doing those things the compiler cannot do that trying to second-guess it.